How do I create a chart that shows influence diagonistics like the image attached below?
I am analyzing set of datas, consisting of 5 independent variables(x1,x2,x3,x4,x5) and a dependent variable(y), with each variable having 60 data.
When I try to run code below to identify the outliers and influential points, but does not present a graph, and dev and c are not calculated properly. How can I fix the code below to show influence diagnostics like the attached screenshot. Thank you.

data data;
INFILE "/home/" dlm=",";
input x1-x5 y;
run;

PROC STANDARD DATA=data MEAN=0 OUT=zdata;
VAR x1-x5;
RUN;

PROC REG DATA=zdata PLOTS;
model y=x1-x5/DWPROB;
RUN;


PROC LOGISTIC DATA=data PLOTS;
MODEL y=x1-x5/ link=glogit INFLUENCE;
OUTPUT OUT=i1 C=c Cbar=c_1 P=p RESCHI=chi RESDEV=dev
DIFCHISQ=chi_s DIFDEV=dev_s H=h C=cookd DFBETAS=ALL;
RUN;

PROC PRINT DATA=i1;
where dev<-2;
var x1-x5 dev;
run;

proc print data=i1;
where c>0.4;
var x1-x5 C;
run;


Can you post some sample data? What does y represent? Is it binary, categorical, or continuous? Depending on what you're trying to predict, you may either need linear or logistic regression, but not both.

@StuSztukowski  thank you for asking and showing interest. A sample data would be y= 380.82 x1=4.031 x2=37.3 x3=127 x4= 6.421 x5= 72.4. each variables would have 60 data to it that have similar values as the example above.

Got it. In this case logistic regression does not seem appropriate to use. y appears to be a continuous variable.

If so, is there an alternative way to create the influential diagonistics chart?

Use the influence option in PROC REG to get influence statistics.
proc reg data=sashelp.iris plots=diagnostics(unpack);
    model SepalLength = PetalLength PetalWidth SepalWidth / influence;
run;

This will give you influence diagnostics, such as Cook's D and Outlier/Leverage points.

